# Is this quote originally from The Dark Knight?

Tags: the-dark-knight, dialogue, origin

> You either die a hero, or live long enough to see yourself become the villain.

Now I'm fairly certain I've been saying that line for at least ten years, don't know where I heard it, but now someone pointed out I was referencing [The Dark Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_%28film%29) and I honestly couldn't believe it when I googled the phrase and found nothing but Dark Knight sites.

That expression must be older than 2008. Right?

Comment: I would actually like it even more if this quote has been around longer than this movie. (just realized the movie is 5 years old)

Comment: Not sure I really care for finding the origin of a quote questions.  Sure, it **might** be from a movie or tv show, but it **might** also be from some other media.

Comment: The quote reminds me of [Hermann Göring's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_G%C3%B6ring) quote: "We will go down in history either as the world's greatest statesmen or its worst villains."

Comment: meta discussion: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/909/should-we-allow-quote-origin-questions

Comment: Not the perfect match, but it reminds me [this quote from Braveheart](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112573/quotes?ref_=tt_trv_qu#qt0440107) `fight and you may die...` part. `Every man dies. Not every man really lives.` by William Wallace is somewhat similar too

Comment: Googling for instances of this quote prior to 2008 and excluding batman, the dark knight and harvey dent, results only in forum signatures, which aren't reliable since many boards render the signatures real-time.

Comment: I don't think you can safely exclude Batman, given the possibility that the quote originates in an older Batman edition. Many sources attribute the quote to one of the original authors, Bill Finger, but I can find no concrete evidence so far.

Comment: ...live long enough to see yourself become that which you most despise." This is the second half of the original quote...more or less. I can't cut through the dark night fog on Google. Grrr.

Comment: Wasn't it said in Spiderman! Pretty sure the Goblin tells it to SM

Comment: @user20795 source?

Comment: @Yannis Oh the dramatic irony of knowing, 80 years later, that he lost the title of "worst villain in history" to Mole Man.

Comment: These are not the only two true outcomes.  This is only true for men who impose their dogma on everyone else.

Comment: _Shutter Island_ (two years later) has another riff on the same idea: “Which would be worse — to live as a monster, or to die as a good man?”

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's highly likely that the quote originated from *The Dark Knight* movie. Apparently, Batman (and other super-heroes) was inspired by Friedrich Nietzsche, a German philosopher. A lot of aspects of Batman are inspired by Nietzsche's beliefs which would explain why the movies seem very philosophical at times.

Along with the fact that there seem to be no references to this quote prior to the movie release (or any variation of it), I conclude that it did in fact originate (at least main stream) from the movie.

- Source: [Nietzsche and the Superhero](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/HeroesInSociety/news/?a=5571)
- Source: [A philosophical basis for the Batman saga](http://fabiusmaximus.com/2008/07/23/batman/)
- Search: Batman + philosophy (tried to add as a link but wouldn't let
  me)
- Search: Batman + Nietzsche (tried to add as a link but wouldn't
  let me)

There is also more proof of this in the book, [Batman and Philosophy: The Dark Knight of the Soul](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470270306). While it doesn't specify the quote, it does discuss the connection between Batman and Nietzsche.

Comment: The closest quote of Nietzsche's is probably this one from _Beyond_ _Good_ _and_ _Evil_: "He who fights with monsters might take care lest he thereby become a monster. And when you gaze long into an abyss the abyss also gazes into you." https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Beyond_Good_and_Evil#Aphorism_146

Comment: @raveturned: related quote by Buckminster Fuller : "Those who play with the devil's toys will be brought by degrees to wield his sword.".

Comment: It's insane this has so many upvotes. Batman didn't become dark and brooding until the 1980s. And most comic book characters aren't remotely philosophical -- in fact "comic book character" is a term used to describe two dimensional characters.

Answer (score 5):

This quote was attributed to Bill Finger who died in 1974, he was best known as the uncredited actual creator of Batman

Comment: The internet indeed attributes the quote to him, but I can't find any verifiable source. If you can, you get the upvote and the accepted answer and I might even create a new bounty just to give it to you because I care about this one. I could have *sworn* it was older than 2008 and I can't find proof. Like, *where* did he say or write this?

Comment: It's possible that the quote was posthumously attributed to him on the web simply as vindication and a statement against DC and Bob Kane.

Answer (score 4):

Although this exact quote may have been first said in the dark knight many men have addressed the philosophy of the corruption of a good man's soul.

"He who fights monsters should see to it that he himself does not become a monster. And if you gaze for long into an abyss, the abyss gazes also into you."
-Frederick Nietzsche.

Answer (score 2):

This quote does originally come from the film. Harvey coins the phrase (no pun intended) in response to Rachel's comment abot Caesar. He isn't using a common expression, but it does come off quite eloquently. Still it is very similar to the philosophy of  Michael Foucault who criticized political and social figures who turn to abusing power for indulgent convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's almost difficult to believe, but sometimes Hollywood coins a phrase that really resonates.

Another example of a phrase that everyone uses but which came from a modern day movie: "**bucket list**" from the film [The Bucket List](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0825232/reference) (2007). Nobody had ever used that phrase before the film was produced.

Source: https://www.wsj.com/articles/the-origins-of-bucket-list-1432909572

So the phrase you pulled out does indeed appear to have originated in The Dark Knight. There is simply no other earlier source for that quote anywhere.

Kudos to Jonathan Nolan and Christopher Nolan for coining something that seems to get truer with each passing year.